# Find the Fourier transform of $u(x) = \frac{x \cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

> Find the Fourier transform of $$u(x) = \frac{x \cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

**My work**

Okay so we want $$\int_\mathbb R \frac{e^{-ixt}x\cos(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$
Of course we want to apply the residue theorem on the function $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{-izt}z\cos(2z)}{(1+z^2)^2}$

But on which path?
I thought; let $z = \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$, we know  that we will want eventually $\rho \to \infty$ to find our integral over $\mathbb R$.

But $$|f(z)| \le \frac{e^{(t-2)\rho\sin\theta} + e^{(t+2)\rho\sin\theta}}{2\rho^3}$$

So if $t < -2$, we can integrate over the positive semicircle as we see that $|f(z)| \to 0$

If $t > 2$, we can integrate over the negative semicircle; again $|f(z)| \to 0$.

But if $-2 < t < 2$? Circles are out of the question; our only hope is to maintain $\rho \sin \theta = \text{Im }(z)$ bounded, so the function still tends to $0$ as those exponential are bounded.

So I thought: let's take the rectangle $[-R, R] \times [0, \frac 12]$. The contour integral will be $0$.
I think I also know how to show that it vanishes over the vertical lines, but I'm having trouble in calculating the upper integral.

**My questions**

1) Is this line of thinking useful? I mean looking when the modulus of $f$ vanishes to find proper path over which integrating

2) How to finish the exercise? Integrating on the upper part seems a mess.

3) Are there easier ways to find this Fourier transform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider the symmetry of the integrand.  The FT is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x \cos{2 x}}{(1+x^2)^2}  \, e^{i k x} $$

The real part of the integrand is odd, so the FT of the real part is zero.  Thus the FT is imaginary:

$$i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x }{(1+x^2)^2}  \,\cos{2 x} \sin{k x} $$

which we may rewrite as

$$\frac{i}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x }{(1+x^2)^2}  \left [\sin{(k+2) x}+\sin{(k-2) x} \right ]$$

So now consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^2} e^{i \kappa z} $$

where $\kappa = k\pm 2$, and $C$ is a semicircular contour of radius $R$ either in the upper or lower half plane according to the sign of $\kappa$.  For example, for $\kappa \gt 0$, we close the contour in the upper half plane, so the contour integral is

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2} e^{i \kappa x} + i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R \, e^{i \theta}}{(1+R^2 e^{i 2 \theta})^2} e^{-\kappa R \sin{\theta}} e^{i \kappa R \cos{\theta}} $$

As $R \to \infty$, the second integral is bounded by

$$\frac{2 R^2}{(R^2-1)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-(2/\pi) \kappa R \theta} = \frac{\pi R}{\kappa (R^2-1)^2} \left (1-e^{-\kappa R} \right )$$

which indeed vanishes as $\pi/R^3$ in this limit.

On the other hand, the integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=i$.  Thus we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2} e^{i \kappa x} &= i 2 \pi \left [\frac{d}{dz} \frac{z\, e^{i \kappa z}}{(z+i)^2} \right ]_{z=i}\\ &= i 2 \pi \left [\frac{(1+i \kappa z) e^{i \kappa z}}{(z+i)^2} - \frac{2 z \, e^{i \kappa z}}{(z+i)^3} \right ]_{z=i} \\ &= i 2 \pi \frac14 \kappa \, e^{-\kappa}\end{align}$$

When $\kappa \lt 0$, we close in the lower half plane, and the analysis is the same, save for the fact that, because one traverses the contour clockwise, the contour integral is $-i 2 \pi$ time the residue at the pole $z=-i$.  The result is that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2} \sin{\kappa x} = \frac{\pi}{2} \kappa \, e^{-|\kappa|}$$

(This is the imaginary part of the FT above.)  Thus, we finally have

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x \cos{2 x}}{(1+x^2)^2}  \, e^{i k x} = i \frac{\pi}{4} \left [(k+2) e^{-|k+2|} + (k-2) e^{-|k-2|} \right ]$$

So to answer your questions:

1) Not really, because it is too difficult to work with the cosine in the complex integrand.  (It blows up on either semicircle as $R \to \infty$.)

2) See above.

3) In my humble opinion, not really.  Mathematica has some different way of going about it algorithmically, and it returns, as the FT,

$$\frac{1}{2} i \pi  e^{k+2} \theta (-k-2)+\frac{1}{4} i \pi  e^{k+2} k \theta (-k-2)-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  e^{k-2} \theta (2-k)+\frac{1}{4} i \pi  e^{k-2} k \theta (2-k)-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  e^{2-k} \theta (k-2)\\+\frac{1}{4} i \pi  e^{2-k} k \theta (k-2)+\frac{1}{2} i \pi  e^{-k-2} \theta (k+2)+\frac{1}{4} i \pi  e^{-k-2} k \theta (k+2)$$

I  verified that this expression is equal to the simple one I returned as the answer.  That said, I don't see how any scheme that returns this answer is any easier than what I have outlined, and even so, you are now left with simplifying this monster, which is no fun.

**ADDENDUM**

I just realized the OP defined the FT using $e^{-i k x}$, so the result will have $-i$ rather than $+i$ in front.

Comment: perfect! Great answer and thank you for the time you put in this problem! So, to my understanding (apart from the calculations, but I would like to "grasp" exactly what happened) we use the symmetry of the integral to get rid of the cosine (who blows up at infinity) thus replacing it with nice exponential in the form "e^{ikx}$. is that correct?

Comment: @Ant: That's correct.  Another approach that's more general is to split the cosine up as $(e^{i 2 x}+e^{-i 2 x})/2$, and use different contours (i.e., upper/lower) for each piece.

Comment: Nice. Thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{-itx}=\cos(tx)-i\sin(tx)$, then the integral can be written as
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\cos(2x)\cos(tx)-ix\cos(2x)\sin(tx)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
The real part of the integrand is an even function, hence its integral value simply equals zero by simmetry. Using trigonometric identity, then
$$I=-\frac{i}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(t+2)x+x\sin(t-2)x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
Let us consider a well-known integral which can be derived by using Fourier transform or complex analysis.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(bx)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{-a|b|}}{a}\quad,\quad\text{for}\,a>0$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $a$ and $b$ once, with the aid of Wolfram Alpha, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2ax\sin(bx)}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx=\pi b\,e^{-a|b|}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(bx)}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi b\,e^{-a|b|}}{2a}$$
Hence
$$I=-\frac{i\pi}{4}\left[(t+2)\,e^{-|t+2|}+(t-2)\,e^{-|t-2|}\right]$$

Comment: Its derivative can be seen here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdb+d%2Fda+Pi+e^%28-a|b|%29%2Fa

Comment: thank you for the answer! I'll probably accept the other answer because it shows how to evaluate the integral, but very interesting answer nonetheless! :)